# When I'm writing to a file deletes everything except the replaced word

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

When I'm trying to write to a file deletes everything in my file except the words I'm trying to replace..

here is my code:

```
app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def writing():
    address_1 = address1()
    address_2 = network1()

    try:
        if request.method =="POST":
            var1 = request.form ['addr1'] 
            var2 = request.form ['addr2']

            changeaddress = [var1, var2]
            address = [address_1, address_2]
            new_var = []
            cur_addr = 0
            new_line = None
            with open('address.txt','r+') as file:
                for line in file:
                    if address[cur_addr] in line:
                        new_line = line.replace(address[cur_addr], changeaddress[cur_addr] + "\n")
                        cur_addr += 1
                    new_var.append(new_line)

            with open('address.txt','w') as file:           
                file.writelines(new_var)

    except BaseException as e:
        print e

    return render_template('addr.html', var1=var1,var2=var2)
```

this is my text file :

```
#######
    Address 192.168.0.3
    Address 192.168.0.1 <--- I'm reading this
######
##############
########
    Network 123.123.0.1 <---- I'm reading this
```

after runing the code for example I replace `192.168.0.1` for `1.1.1.1` and `123.123.0.1` for `0.0.0.0` I get this:

```
Address 1.1.1.1
Network 0.0.0.0
```

As you can see it deleting everything except what I replaced. I would like to get something like this:

```
#######
    Address 192.168.0.3
    Address 1.1.1.1
######
##############
########
    Network 0.0.0.0
```

So my app should not  replace  the lines I want to replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only adding the replaced line to the list that you write.

As I said in a previous question, indent the new line, and in case it wasn't clear there, append the non-replaced line.

```
if address[cur_addr] in line:
    # replace 
    new_var.append(new_line)
else:
    # keep 
    new_var.append(line)
```